# How to detect web account vulnerability

Tags: webserver, web, http-basic-auth

I know I might take a lot of flack for asking this basic question, but I hope you'll be patient with me. I was looking at a few websites and analyzing the payload when sending a POST request to login.

ON GitHub, for example, I can see both username and password when sending the request.

[image: GitHub]

Whereas, on ProtonMail, which is supposed to be a very secure mail, I can only see the username, but not the password, which is good obviously.

[image: ProtonMail]

So, my question is if I can see the password in the request, does it mean the site is vulnerable? Is one prone to a MITM attack if logging in using a free WiFi? Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Are you using https to access Github? Did you accept/ignore any certificate warnings when connecting to it?

Comment: I am using HTTPS. I have not had any certificate warnings. Also, I'm using Brave, which is technically more secure than other browsers.

Comment: @user I've just tried it on Chrome and Firefox, and they all show the password as plain text.

Comment: Since it's over HTTPS, that form data is encrypted. It looks like ProtonMail is sending json payloads, but most likely it is also sending plaintext in the secure connection.

Comment: That's what it looks like, and it's terrifying. Any idea why and how to fix it?

Comment: Why is it terrifying? The data is encrypted already. You don't need to fix it.

Comment: I mean, it may also be sending plain text. Otherwise, it wouldn't show, right? I tried it on gmail, and nothing shows. I tried on another supposedly secure mail and the password shows. I'm confused.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Username and password stored under form data in Chrome Dev Tools](/questions/51186/), [Inspecting code elements in browser when logging in](/questions/185511/), [Passing plain text password over HTTPS](/questions/233759/).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes it, does. Thank you!